# Numpy - select multiple squares from 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d array, and a list of <start_y, height, start_x, width>.
What I need is to select squares according to the list,
So, for example if this is my 2d array:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]]
```

and the list is:

```
[[1,3,2,5],
 [2,2,0,3]]
```

I need the output to be:

```
[[12,13,14,15,16, 
  22,23,24,25,26,
  32,33,34,35,36],
 [20,21,22,
  30,31,32]]
```

i.e. - the first square starts from index 1 in the y axis, with height of 3, and in index 2 in the x axis with width of 5 - and the same logic for the second element in the list.

I obviously tried things like `arr[l[:,0]:l[:,0]+l[:,1],l[:,2]:l[:,2]+l[:,3]]` where arr is the array and l is the list, but it all returned an invalid syntax error.

I guess the solution involves advanced broadcasting, but I couldn't figure it out by my own.

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT:

I'm looking for a solution without `for` loop (it is currently implemented with a loop, and I'm looking to make my code more efficient).

Comment: Probably can't beat just basic iteration here, since your slices are jagged.  `[a[i:i+j, k:k+l] for i, j, k, l in idx]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a difficulty: your squares are of different sizes. Most broadcasting or useful functions will result in one array. If your squares were the same size, we could probably figure out how to get a stacked version of them into a 3d array. But if they're different sizes, how would we stack them? Nothing wrong with a for-loop here.

Read this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

No "advanced broadcasting" needed.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
 [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,],
 [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,],
 [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,],
 ])

 
coords = np.array([
 [1,3,2,5],
 [2,2,0,3],
 ])
 
for coord in coords:
    y, h, x, w = coord
    sq = arr[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    print(sq)
```

Might be easier in your code to make a function

```
def get_square(arr, coord):
    y, h, x, w = coord
    return arr[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

Comment: Yeah... I meant without a for loop, sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @BinyaminEven  I added this to the answer: Here's a difficulty: your squares are of different sizes. Most broadcasting or useful functions will result in one array. If your squares were the same size, we could probably figure out how to get a stacked version of them into a 3d array. But if they're different sizes, how would we stack them? Nothing wrong with a for-loop here.  For loop doesn't always mean less efficient--if you want to make your code more efficient, start timing things and fix the slowest parts first., instead of assuming the anecdote that for loop = bad holds here.

Comment: Thanks man, I upvoted, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve for loop (if there is such a thing, from my experience if you are a pro in broadcasting you can make many miracles :) )

Comment: @BinyaminEven No prob--see the comment though. For one, I think broadcasting will be tricky since your resulting squares will be different sizes.  Secondly, a for-loop here probably wouldn't bottleneck your code compared to some (say it exists) built-in function for this. Good luck!